# Media Player - Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I need some help with my media player.......the debugger keep on telling me that the media player is null:

I did a toast and seems like the media player is still null after I create it: and no, my uri is not null!

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
```

Log Cat:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
```

Media Player:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Code:

```
    public void playSongs() {
            if (PlayingScreen_List != null) {
                uri = Uri.parse(PlayingScreen_List.get(position).getPath());
            }
    
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);
    

//After I did a toast it keeps telling me that the media player is null 

                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mediaPlayer + " Media Player"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(uri + " Uri"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri);

//After I did a toast it keeps telling me that the media player is null after I create it

                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(mediaPlayer + " Media Player else"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(uri + " Uri else"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to instatiate a new MediaPlayer like this(this will not work):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

You only need to call the 'create()' method which is the correct way to generate the new MediaPlayer object for you:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_sound);
```

example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_sound);

}

void playSound(){ mediaPlayer.play(); }
void stopSound()throuws IOException { mediaPlayer.stop(); }
```

Comment: Hello! Thx for replying.

Comment: MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); --> is above the onCreate method. Also, I don't have any audio files in my resource folder...I am trying to play the audio by parsing it's path.

Comment: Also, the mediaPlayer may be returning null because of the second "if" in playSong(), which should be: if (mediaPlayer == null), if you did not call create() before the playSongs() method, it will never enter the if (mediaPlayer != null) condition.

Comment: Thank you! I highly appreciate the help...But is there any chance that you can rewrite the code above to what you think will fix the bug....Honestly I am a little confused. Thank you very much!!!!!